How to use !Sub both for Key: Value in Cloudformation template?
Stuck with CLoudFormatino Role definition:
Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
Properties:
...
  AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
    Version: "2012-10-17"
    Statement:
      ...
      - Effect: "Allow"
        Principal:
          Federated: ...
        Action: "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity"
        Condition:
          StringEquals:
            "oidc.eks.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/id/${ClusterID}:sub": !Sub "system:serviceaccount:${Namespace}:${ServiceName}"

For given example - is will replace second part - "system:serviceaccount:${Namespace}:${ServiceName}" with values of vars Namespace and ServiceName
But How I can apply !Sub for the key also - oidc.eks.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/id/${ClusterID}:sub ?
Tried a lot of options, all of them gave me template error:
StringEquals:
  !Sub
    - "${OidcKey}": "system:serviceaccount:${Namespace}:${ServiceName}"
    - OidcKey: "oidc.eks.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/id/${ClusterID}:sub"

...
StringEquals:
  !Sub "oidc.eks.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/id/${ClusterID}:sub": "system:serviceaccount:${Namespace}:${ServiceName}"

How to use variables (replace with vars) both for Key: Value?

I think the same was discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60648476/using-a-parameter-value-as-a-key-in-cloudformation

This link could be the answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/75017602
